# Dual booting windows 8 and Kali Linux 1.0.8

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, boot, bootrepair

I'm trying to install kali linux along with windows 8
The latest Kali version (1.0.8) supports booting alongside windows 8

I installed Kali Linux from a LiveCD, rebooted and it went straight to windows. I thought I should use boot-repair

I used my ubuntu liveCD and used boot-repair in the hopes of it installing GRUB that will either allow me to boot into windows 8 or Kali Linux

Boot-repair was running fine but in the end it failed.

I was hoping if someone could help me with my problem
This is the dump of boot-repair: [Dump](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7940171/)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 typically has a disabled legacy boot and boot menu by default in the BIOS. It will always boot Windows 8 first and only unless your BIOS is configured to startup in a boot menu so you can choose what partition to boot from.

I assume you are using 1 drive with 2 partitions, one with Kali and one with Windows. Grub doesn't necessarily give you that boot menu option, it's just a required utility to boot an UNIX machine.

I believe I can answer more if you can give me more Info on what happens when you boot your pc, if it goes directly into Windows 8 or how do you boot into the other OS? And if you even were able to do that in the first place. If I can recommend anything, I would say maybe a custom BIOS would be required, or have you ever thought about VM?

Comment: Update: I found this website very useful, maybe you can too: http://www.isoc.my/profiles/blogs/continuing-my-adventures-with-uefi-windows-8-1-kali-linux-dual

Answer (score 0):

Update: use a free non cometcial use of EasyBCD, it will fix any boot problems, create boot partitions and allow you to dual boot into any OS with a single click of a button.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Windows 10 preview, and was able to install grub normally. Mount your ext4 partition to /mnt, bind /dev and /proc, cp /etc/resolv.conf, chroot into /mnt and run grub-install /dev/sda (or whatever HDD you need). Ask if you need more detailed instructions.